# Screen problems connecting laptop to tv via VGA HDMI cable - screen resets

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have recently purchased a VGA-HDMI converter to connect my laptop to Samsung HD TV.  Initially, the connection works fine (picture and sound) but then after a few minutes, the connection will reset itself, leaving the screen blank with no sound for a few seconds before picture and sound returns.  This keeps on repeating itself every few minutes.

I don't know how to fix this, and haven't been able to find an answer searching the internet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but could be a faulty vga to HDMI converter. It'll be converting the analogue signal to digital to be able to display over HDMI, so it may be tripping up every so often and dropping the signal to your box. Try a different converter if you have access to one, or a different computer and see if you get the same issue.